# Multiple effect overlays with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

This subject was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195872/applying-multiple-filters-at-once-with-ffmpeg) before but my problem is a little different.
I have a transparent tiff sequence with sequential numbers that I wish to overlay on top of another tiff sequence in order to create a video file.

In addition, I'd like to add a text overlay from a text file using the drawtext filter.

Seperatly, I've managed to do both of these actions but when I try to combine them to a single command line, the code either doesn't work or it produces only one of the video filters.

This is the code I've used for the sequential numbers overlay:

```
ffmpeg -i sc060_sh0050_v02.%4d.tif -i %d.tif -vcodec v210 -filter_complex overlay -shortest 00output.mov
```

And this is the code I've used for the title overlay:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i sc060_sh0050_v02.%4d.tif -vcodec v210 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: fontsize=50: textfile=filename.txt: r=25: x=100: y=(lh): fontcolor=0x76FF08: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099[out]" -y 00output.mov
```

Does anyone know of a way I can make both effects work in a single command line?

Comment: what's the failing command line?

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg \
-i sc060_sh0050_v02.%4d.tif \
-i %d.tif \
-vcodec v210 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay,drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf:fontsize=50:textfile=filename.txt: r=25: x=100: y=(lh): fontcolor=0x76FF08: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" \
-shortest \
-y \
test.mov
```

1. You must use filter_complex because an overlay has two inputs.
2. First overlay sequence **%d.tiff** over **sc060_sh0050_v02.%4d.tif**
3. Add the drawtext filter. Note the comma between overlay and
   drawtext chains the filters.